# Unable to delete model in Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to delete a database entry through the associated model using `->delete()`, but the entry is not deleted.

I tried changing the form from POST to DELETE, but that made no difference. And research around SO didn't yield anything either.

Prefered I would like to avoid using `Model::destroy($ids)`, <s>which does seem to work.</s>

The route methods:

```
// Delete an asset
public function getDelete($id)
{
    // Try to find the asset, throw exception if not found
    $asset = Asset::findOrFail($id);

    $this->layout->title = 'Delete an asset';
    $this->layout->content = View::make('asset.delete')
            ->with('assetID', $id);
}

// Delete the actual asset
public function postDelete()
{
    $id = Input::get('AID');

    // Try to find the asset, throw exception if not found
    $asset = Asset::findOrFail($id);

    // Attempt to delete it
    if($asset->delete())
    {
        return Redirect::route('asset')
                ->with('success', 'The asset has been deleted succesfully!');
    }

    return Redirect::route('asset')
            ->with('failure', 'The asset could not be deleted. Please try again.');
}
```

The routes:

```
/* Route to deleting an asset
 * Shorthand: URL::route('deleteAsset')
 * Uses AssetController::getDelete
 */
Route::get('/asset/delete/{id}', array(
    'as' => 'deleteAsset',
    'uses' => 'AssetController@getDelete'
));

/* Route to actually deleting an asset
 * Shorthand: URL::route('deleteAssetPost')
 * Uses AssetController::postDelete
 */
Route::delete('/asset/delete/', array(
    'as' => 'deleteAssetPost',
    'uses' => 'AssetController@postDelete'
));
```

The model:

```
class Asset extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'Asset';

    protected $primaryKey = 'AID';

    protected $fillable = array('ACID', 'AKID', 'AATID', 'APurchaseDate');

    // Retrieve the customer's name associated with the asset
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Customer', 'CID', 'ACID');
    }

    // Retrieve the asset type that is associated with the asset
    public function assetType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('AssetType', 'ATID', 'AATID');
    }

    // Get the customer name
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->customer()->first()->CName;
    }

    // Get the asset type name
    public function getAssetTypeName()
    {
        return $this->assetType()->first()->ATName;
    }

    // Get the associated key
    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->AKID === -1 ? 'nvt' : $this->AKID;
    }

    // Get the purchase date in readable form
    public function getPurchaseDate($format = 'd-m-Y')
    {
        return date($format, strtotime($this->APurchaseDate));
    }
}
```

According to the controller the deletion is successful and it gives the success message.

No errors are thrown.

**[edit]**

Does anyone know what I'm missing here to make this work?

After logging the queries, the following queries are executed using `$asset->delete()`:

```
select * from `Asset` where `AID` = ? limit 1
delete from `Asset` where `AID` = ?
```

I tried the same thing with `Asset::destroy($id)`, results from that are:

```
select * from `Asset` where `AID` = ? limit 1
select * from `Asset` where `AID` in (?)
delete from `Asset` where `AID` = ?
```

Comment: That's a tough one - everything looks correct to me. When you say it fails, what do you mean? You said the `->delete()` method returns true, so presumably it's silently failing (i.e. the row is not deleted). Your model doesn't appear to use soft deletes but you should ensure that's not the case here. Also it may be worth logging your SQL queries so you can see 1) if any SQL is executed and 2) if so, what it's trying to do.

Comment: @alexrussell It's exactly how you describe it. It says it deleted the row but in reality it doesn't. My model indeed doesn't use soft deletes, nor have I looked into them yet. I'll try logging the query and get back to you on that.

Comment: @alexrussell I edited my question with the logged queries.

Comment: @RichardA so the delete query is running.. you saying that even after that query you can find that 'aid' in your DB? check in your DB maybe you have some caching in your code

Comment: @amirbar The asset with that id remains in the database. I don't think I have database caching. But if I do, where can I find that out?

Comment: @RichardA It'd be interesting to see what the log output is when you use the `Model::delete($ids);` method, so see how it differs.

Comment: Also have you inspected the database directly (Sequel Pro, phpMyAdmin, etc.) or are you relying on some view made by Laravel? Because that's where the caching could be.

Comment: @alexrussell I'm assuming you mean `Model::destroy($ids)`. And yes, I have checked PhpMyAdmin to see if the entry is deleted, it's still there.

Comment: @alexrussell Updates my answer using `Asset::destroy($id)`

Comment: Well that's very weird - same SQL. It'd be interesting to see what the bound parameters are. Sorry I'm not sure I can help. I'd probably have to be there poking around in your database.

Comment: @alexrussell Any way to find out what the bound parameters are?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure unfortunately. I think if there was an exception you could get them, but simply listening to the database.query event (or whatever it is) you only get the SQL as a string, which is a shame.

Comment: @alexrussell Is there any way that the relations could have anything to do with it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47952/discussion-between-alexrussell-and-richard-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of discussion in chat we realised that the code was defining a `getKey()` method on the model which was used for a domain-specific purpose. However, this is actually a method that Eloquent defines on all models, and it uses it pretty heavily. In this case, Eloquent's `delete` method was calling `getKey()` to determine the model's ID.

The reason for the non-error was that although the delete itself was failing to delete (as it was trying to delete a model with ID of 'nvt'), it wasn't technically doing anything worth erroring about as it was perfectly valid code/SQl: `` DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 'nvt'; ``

Comment: I renamed the method to `getAssetKey()` and now it works like a charm. Thanks a bunch for the help! For those interested, [here is the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47952/discussion-between-alexrussell-and-richard-a)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: Hehe, glad you found the answer useful.